# Swap specific chars in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

How can I swap characters in a string in Python?

For example:

```
text = 'gghghg didjf ekofrhhwehg'
```

I want to swap all of the 'g' in the text for 'k'.

Would I use `ord()` and `chr()` functions?

Update: 
When i run this code:

```
text = 'gghghg didjf ekofrhhwehg'
text.replace("g", "k")

print text
```

It doesnt change the output

Comment: You wouldn't. Too short to comment.

Comment: 'ggghg...'.replace('g', 'k')

Comment: Do you want to swap (meaning k → g and g → k) or do you want to just replace? (meaning g → k)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use, [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), like this

```
>>> text = 'gghghg didjf ekofrhhwehg'
>>> text.replace("g", "k")
kkhkhk didjf ekofrhhwehk
```

Alternatively, you can create a translation table and use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), like this

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> text.translate(maketrans("g", "k"))
kkhkhk didjf ekofrhhwehk
```

**Note:** If you actually meant swapping all `g`s with `k`s and vice-versa then you should use `str.translate`, like this

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> 'gluke'.translate(maketrans("gk", "kg"))
kluge
```

See how `g` in `gluke` changed to `k` and `k` in `gluke` changed to `g`, in the result.

---

About your edit, Python Strings are immutables. So once you create a String object, you can never change its value. You just have to create a new one. So, assign the result of `text.replace` back to `text`, like this

```
>>> text = 'gghghg didjf ekofrhhwehg'
>>> text = text.replace("g", "k")
>>> text
kkhkhk didjf ekofrhhwehk
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @thefourtheye

Comment: text = 'gghghg didjf ekofrhhwehg'
text.replace("g", "k")

print text

Comment: but when i run
text = 'gghghg didjf ekofrhhwehg'
text.replace("g", "k")

print text

it doesnt change the output

Comment: @JeffCrackalack Try, `text = text.replace("g", "k")`. Python Strings are immutable. So once created you cannot change it. You need to construct a new String object only.

Comment: @JeffCrackalack Please check my answer now. I included a solution to the problem in your edit. Did that help?

Comment: Thanks appreciate it! but it was for a simple decryption problem using another string and i thought replacing some letters would solve it. But i guess I have to replace the letters first then after use ord() and chr() in a loop(?) in order to decypt it :(

Answer (score 1):

Just use [replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
In [1]: text = 'gghghg didjf ekofrhhwehg'

In [2]: text.replace("g", "k")

Out[2]: 'kkhkhk didjf ekofrhhwehk'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use built-in tools also.

```
>>> def trans(s):
        m = ''
        for i in s:
            if i == 'g':
                i = 'k'
                m += i
            elif i == 'k':
                i = 'g'
                m += i
            else:
                m += i
        return m

>>> print(trans('gluke'))
kluge
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this:

```
text = 'gghghg didjf ekofrhhwehg'
text = text.replace("g", "k")
print text
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already demonstrate how to replace characters.

To swap characters you could do the following, given that `_` does not appear in the string:

```python
text = 'gghghg didjf ekofrhhwehg'
text = text.replace("g", "_").replace("k", "g").replace("_", "k")
print text
```